# JMeter multiple or nested users/threads

Tags: multithreading, jmeter

The system I am trying to test involves various users interacting with various events.

I'd like to create a JMeter scenario as follows:

There are 10 users and 50 events.  The test will generate a total of 50 interactions (API calls) per second, with interactions distributed evenly across all users and events.  In other words, each user will generate 5 interactions with a different event each second.  There will be only one interaction per event per second, and no users will overlap in the events they are interacting with.

Using either a CSV/TXT file with a list of 10 users or a CSV/TXT file of a list of 50 events, I am able to separately create either 10 threads of users or 50 threads of events.  However, I am not able to create them together in the same script.

As a result, I am only able to create a script that generates 10 users interacting with one event, or one user interacting with 50 events.

Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'd create a test with 10 threads and two different CSV files. One CSV file with 10 users and one with 50 events. If the CSV Dataset config sharing mode is set to All Threads then you can have each of the 10 users calling different events.